# How to find the derivative of $x^2\sin(x)$ using only the limit definition of a derivative?

Tags: limits, derivatives

I’m trying to find the derivative of $x^2\sin x$ using only the limit definition of a derivative. I’ve tried two approaches, one using the difference quotient and another with the regular $x-a$ formula.

I’m stumped on both approaches and not sure where to go. Maybe I’m on the wrong track completely. The difference quotient gets messy quickly and I can’t figure out how to factor out $h$ to get it into a definable form. So then I tried: $$\frac{x^2\sin(x) - a^2\sin(a)}{x-a}.$$

Is it possible to apply the trig sum-to-product form to the numerator? I’m really just guessing playing around with identities trying to figure this out. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{(x+h)^{2}\sin(x+h)-x^{2}\sin x}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{(x+h)^{2}\sin(x+h)-x^{2}\sin(x+h)+x^{2}\sin(x+h)-x^{2}\sin x}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{((x+h)^{2}-x^{2})\sin(x+h)}{h}+\dfrac{x^{2}(\sin(x+h)-\sin x)}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{(2hx+h^{2})\sin(x+h)}{h}+\dfrac{x^{2}(\sin x\cos h+\cos x\sin h-\sin x)}{h}\\
&=(2x+h)\sin(x+h)+x^{2}\cdot\dfrac{\cos h-1}{h}+x^{2}\cos x\cdot\dfrac{\sin h}{h}\\
&\rightarrow 2x\sin x+x^{2}\cos x.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

For limits of products, you always need to add a and subtract. In this case, $a^2\sin x$. Then 
\begin{align} 
\frac{x^2\sin x - a^2\sin a}{x-a}&=
\frac{x^2\sin x - a^2\sin x}{x-a} 
+
\frac{a^2\sin x- a^2\sin a}{x-a}\\ 
&=
\frac{x^2 - a^2}{x-a}\, \sin x
+
a^2\,\frac{\sin x - \sin a}{x-a}. 
\end{align}

Comment: I remember this method now and also remember not understanding the rational behind adding $a$ (the right hand side). Is there a simple way to explain where this comes from?

Comment: It's the natural way to deal with it. If you can control $a-c$ and $b-c$, then $$ab-cd=ab-cb+cb-cd=(a-c)b+c(b-d).$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{\Bbb d}{\Bbb dx}(x^2\sin x)\big|_{x=a} &= \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{x^2\sin x-a^2\sin a}{x-a} \\
&= \lim_{x\rightarrow a} \left(\frac{x^2\sin x-a^2\sin x}{x-a}+\frac{a^2\sin x-a^2\sin a}{x-a}\right) \\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \left( \sin (x)\cdot (x+a)+a^2\frac{\sin ((x-a)+a)-\sin a}{x-a} \right) \\
&=2a\sin a+a^2\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{\sin (x-a)\cos a+\cos(x-a)\sin a-\sin a}{x-a}\\
&=2a\sin a+a^2\cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow a}\left(\cos a\cdot \frac{\sin(x-a)}{x-a}+\sin a\cdot\frac{\cos(x-a)-1}{x-a}\right)\\
&=2a\sin a+a^2(\cos a\cdot 1+\sin a\cdot0)\\
&=2a\sin a+a^2\cos a
\end{align}