# Derivative of a function using definition at a point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find the derivative of the function $f(x)=x^2\sin x$ at $x=\pi/2$. Using the definition of the derivative, I got:
$$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)} \frac{x^2\sin x-(\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

I can't seem to be able to come up with any of the common factorising methods that can be used to remove the indeterminable denominator. Is there any way to manipulate this?

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to \pi/2}$ is the limit

Comment: Yes, apologies, I'll change that typo

Comment: For solve it, try the change $y=x-\pi/2$ and use that $\sin(y+\pi/2)=\cos(y)$

Comment: Seems been done here: [how to find derivative of $x^2\sin(x)$ using only the limit definition of a derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462253/how-to-find-derivative-of-x2-sinx-using-only-the-limit-definition-of-a-deri)

Answer (score 2):

You have$$x^2\sin(x)-\left(\frac\pi2\right)^2=x^2\sin(x)-x^2+x^2-\left(\frac\pi2\right)^2,$$and therefore it is enough to check that both limits$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{x^2\sin(x)-x^2}{x-\pi/2}\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{x^2-(\pi/2)^2}{x-\pi/2}$$exist. And this is easy, since$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{x^2\sin(x)-x^2}{x-\pi/2}=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}x^2\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(\pi/2)}{x-\pi/2}$$and$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{x^2-(\pi/2)^2}{x-\pi/2}=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)\frac{x-\pi/2}{x-\pi/2}.$$

Comment: Interesting insght as always in these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$f'(\pi /2)= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(\pi /2 +h)^2 \sin(\pi /2 +h)-(\pi ^2 /4 )\sin(\pi /2)}{h}=$$

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{(\pi /2 +h)^2 -\pi ^2 /4 }{h}=\pi $$

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the equivalent alternative form of the definition of derivative, which is often easier to simplify in practice:
$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)}{\Delta x}.$$

Then in this example, the quotient whose limit you need to find takes the form:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\Delta x\right)^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\Delta x\right)-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}{\Delta x} &= \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\Delta x\right)^2\cos(\Delta x)-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}{\Delta x} = \\
&= \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2\left(\cos(\Delta x)-1\right)+\pi\Delta x\cos(\Delta x)+(\Delta x)^2\cos(\Delta x)}{\Delta x} = \\
&= \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2\cdot\frac{\cos(\Delta x)-1}{\Delta x}+\pi\cos(\Delta x)+\Delta x\cos(\Delta x),
\end{aligned}$$
and then use the special limit for $\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to0}\dfrac{\cos(\Delta x)-1}{\Delta x}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let's observe that now we can use the L'Hospital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{x^2\sin(x)-x^2}{x-\pi/2}=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}x^2\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(\pi/2)}{x-\pi/2} = (L.H.R.) = \lim_{x\to\pi/2}2x\cos(x) + x^2 \sin(x) - 2x $$ and$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{x^2-(\pi/2)^2}{x-\pi/2}=\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\left(x+\frac\pi2\right)\frac{x-\pi/2}{x-\pi/2} (L.H.R.) = \lim_{x\to\pi/2} 2x$$

Can you finish from this?